# C++11 Uniform initialization (i.e. list initialization) doesn't compile with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, compiler-errors, list-initialization

```
struct B { 
  int b; 
  B(int i = 0) : b(i) {};  // constructor
};

struct D : B  {
  int d;
};

int main () {
  D obj = {1};  // <-- error
  // D obj {1}; // <-- error (different)

}
```

Above code doesn't compiles, and gives:

```
error: could not convert ‘{1}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘D’
```

The same is true, even if I remove the "constructor" line.
If I remove `=` sign, i.e. `D obj {1};` then it gives below:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘D::D(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

What is the correct syntax to fix such issue?

Comment: Are you expecting it to default-construct the `B` and initialise `d` with `1`? Or initialise the `B` with `1` and leave `d` uninitialised? Either way, you'll need a constructor to resolve the ambiguity (or default-construct it then set the members to what you want). Brace initialisation only works for aggregates or classes with a matching constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, The error remains, even if we **remove** the "constructor" line in `struct B`.

Comment: Of course it does. As I said, "brace initialisation only works for aggregates or classes with a matching constructor". You'll need to either give `D` a suitable constructor, or default-construct it and set its members after construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`D` doesn't have a constructor taking an `int`. If you want it to inherit `B`'s constructor, say so, like this:

```
struct D : B  {
  using B::B;
  int d;
};
```

You probably want to do more than that though, given that `D` has another `int` member.

A more complete `D` which initialises both `B::b` (by calling `B::B`) and `D::d` would probably look like this:

```
struct D : B  {
  D(int d_) : B(d_), d(d_) {}
  int d;
};
```

Either way, your code needs to say `D` has a constructor taking an `int`.

Link to working example using your code and my snippet: http://goo.gl/YbSSHn

Comment: The error remains, even if you remove the "constructor" line in `struct B`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @iammilind. I linked to a working example which compiles fine. Can you demonstrate what you think is still broken?

Comment: Whoops, good catch, @Jarod42. I think I'd seen so many Ds and Bs my mind was going blank.

Answer (score 1):

In what you've written `D` has only a default constructor and does not know how to invoke `B::B(int i)`. All you have to do is to provide a corresponding constructor in `D` like:

```
struct D : B  {
  D(int i) : B(i) {}//;
  int d;
};
```

Comment: You have propagated iammilind's redundant semicolon! I wasn't going to say anything, but that's two of you now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll comment the semicolon out :)

Comment: That solution would not have occurred to me!

Comment: Nor to me. I just don't want to erase the content that has been commented.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. My comment means "I would never have thought of that solution myself." (But I like it.)